# Unity 5.3.2 - Can't use UI Text object in inspector

Tags: javascript, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

So I upgraded to Unity 5.3.2 last night, and now I can't drag a UI Text object into a script in the inspector. (Images below)

[image]

[image]

There are no compiler errors, except at runtime. I get this error every time:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
`Scoring.updateScores () (at Assets/Scripts/Scoring.js:21)`

I have the javascript code below. The comments are things I have tried. Please ask for and needed clarification.

```
#pragma strict

var score : int;
//var scoreScore : GameObject;
//var highScore : GameObject;
var scoreScore : UnityEngine.UI.Text;
var highScore : UnityEngine.UI.Text;

function Start () {
    //scoreScore = GameObject.Find("scoreScore").GetComponent.<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    //highScore = GameObject.Find("highScore").GetComponent.<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    score = 0;
    updateScores();
}

function updateScores() {
    if (score >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore")) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", score);
    }

    scoreScore.text = "" + score.ToString();
    highScore.text = "" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore");
}
```

Comment: of course there are no compile errors, the error occurs when trying to access the null variables, what are you trying to drag to them??

Comment: I am trying to drag UI Text elements from the hierarchy

Comment: I can grab and drag them, I just can't drop them

Comment: are u sure what you are dragging is a Text element? the only case unity won't allow you if the game object you are dragging doesn't have UIText component attached to it, to make sure, click on the right circle and try to choose your objects from the menu not by dragging

Comment: Hmmm... I made the object using Create>UI>Text. Does that work?

Comment: it should work of course this is the most basic way to create Text element, try to do what I said to try and isolate the error

Comment: Nothing appears in the menu when I click the circle. Why?

Comment: The name on the component on the object is Text (Script) Why is this?

Comment: This means there are no Text elements in your scene ! this is odd, I'm not very familiar in js scripting in unity, having nothing in that menu means u don't have text objects, did you try to create a new one? what do you mean why script? this is how the component is called

Comment: I have 4 text elements though! I am using the stackexchange app right now. I will update the question with a screenshot of the hierarchy when I get back to my pc

Comment: I don't know what is missing, I tried exactly what you did and it's working perfectly, tried another scene? restarting unity?

Comment: Haven't tried another scene, did restart unity. I'll try restarting again and then do a new scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at a *script* in the Inspector (by clicking on it within the Assets folder), you can set the default objects for that script. These objects can only be from your Sssets- it will not allow you to drag objects from within a certain scene. You can only drag objects from a scene to instances of scripts within that scene (e.g. a Scoring script attatched to a certain GameObject).

Try creating a GameObject, attaching the Scoring script to it, selecting that *GameObject* in the inspector, and the dragging the UIText elements to the instance of the script you attached to that GameObject.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop those text objects to your project, make them prefab. Then you can assign them.

Comment: This question is 4 and a half years old but I appreciate the answer